# Mongo DB manual splitting in Command Prompt

Tags: mongodb, split

I am new to Mongodb, I have a Video file placed in Gridfs. I want to split this file before retrieving it(according to the requirement, it has to be played for a particular time period). 
I tried using the **split** command in **command prompt** but it throws an error as below,

```
db.runCommand({split:"Videotest.Video",find: { _id : ObjectId("5600d78428932c141c000002")}})
      "ok" : 0,
      "errmsg" : "no such command: split",
      "code" : 59,
      "bad cmd" : {
              "split" : "Videotest.Video",
              "find" : {
                      "_id" : ObjectId("5600d78428932c141c000002")
              }
      }
```

Should i use fs.chunks instead of Video collection? which command should be used to split this video file? am bit confused. I seek your inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are connected to a mongos instance? If not try to do so.

The system complains that command is not available, which makes sense if you are connected to a mongod as the command is not available there.